# Is the maximum size of an item in a type 19 file configurable?

Tags: universe

A WRITEBLK command fails when the item reaches 2GB in size (item is truncated to 2147483647 bytes).

Using cat I was able to create an item larger than 2GB in the same directory, but opening it in UV gave a corrupt (negative) value for STATUS<4> (Number of bytes available to read).

```
uv 11.1.4
64bit Linux on a VM
64BIT_FILES = 1
```

Comment: See this thread: http://u2-universe-unidata.1073795.n5.nabble.com/Universe-file-size-limits-td9129.html Maybe this is an OS limitation instead of a UniVerse one?

Comment: Thanks - I remember those days - when both Windows and Linux had that 2 GB limitation.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the universe files 32 or 64 bit (regardless of the OS).  So you can do a FILEINFO call to see if the file is actually 64bit (even if the account is 64bit).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is an File system limitation on the file size. in the [Rocket UniVerse documentation (page 927)](https://docs.rocketsoftware.com/nxt/gateway.dll/RKBnew20%2Funiverse%2Fprevious%20versions%2Fv11.2.3%2Funiverse_basiccommandsrefguide_v1123.pd) it says:

> If the device runs out of disk
>   space, WRITEBLK takes the ELSE clause and returns –4 to the STATUS
>   function.

Generally only 32 bit systems would be the hard limit on 2 GB, but maybe there is some kind of 32 bit process running in our 64 bit virtual machine that is producing the same effect. See here for a few leads: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274380/file-size-limit

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I was able to sh out and create an item in the type 19 directory larger than 2GB by using cat to join some smaller files.  I wonder if WRITEBLK is implemented with some 32 bit routine.